# Digital clock c++

Tags: c++, struct, clock

Making a digital clock in c++ and I get these errors:
expected ; before reloj
statement is a reference, not call, to funcion 'time'
statement has no effect
''reloj'' is undeclared (first use this function)
Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;
struct time
{
int hr,mint,seg;
};

int main()
{
time reloj;

reloj.hr = 0;
reloj.mint = 0;
reloj.seg = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<24; i++)
{
    if(reloj.hr == 23)
    {
        reloj.hr = 0;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<60; j++)
    {
        if(reloj.mint == 59)
        {
            reloj.mint = 0;
        }
        for(int k = 0; k<60; k++)
        {
            if(reloj.seg == 59)
            {
                reloj.seg = 0;
            }
            cout<<reloj.hr<<" : "<<reloj.mint<<" : "<<reloj.seg<<endl;
            reloj.seg++;
            Sleep(1000);
            system("Cls");
        }
        reloj.mint++;
    }
    reloj.hr++;
}
}
```

Comment: I'll bet it has something to do with `std::time`.

Comment: Your "clock" is going to drift out as the sleep will be too long (the other bits of code takes time along with the fact that sleep is the minimum. Sometime will take a little more due to the computer executing another process)

Comment: `time` => `struct time` in deklaration of `reloj`

Comment: I got the code, compiled it and it ran fine. I used VS-2013 express. What compiler are you using? Also, chris' suggestion seems possible. Try renaming your struct to something other than "time".

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace std;` in the global namespace is a bad idea, and is probably dumping `std::time` there, along with a host of other names. This will clash with your `time` class.

Unfortunately, simply removing the evil `using` isn't a solution here, since `time` comes from the C library. Implementations are allowed to (and many do) dump names from the C library into the global namespace whether you want them there or not.

So your options are:

- Rename your class, or put it in your own namespace;
- Refer to it as `struct time` rather than just `time`;
- Don't include any standard library headers, just in case they mess with your global names.

Answer (score 0):

I have Another codes :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void Timer()
{
    int HOUR = 0, MINUTE = 0 , SECOND = 0;

    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

    HOUR = ltm->tm_hour;
    MINUTE = ltm->tm_min;
    SECOND = ltm->tm_sec;

    while(true)
    {
        system("clear");
        cout << HOUR << ":" << MINUTE << ":" << SECOND << endl;
        SECOND ++;

        if(SECOND == 60)
        {
            MINUTE++;
            SECOND = 0;

            if(MINUTE == 60);
            {
                HOUR++;
                MINUTE = 0;

                if(HOUR ==24)
                {
                    HOUR = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Timer();
}
```

*IF YOU USE THIS ON WINDOWS THEN CHANGE system("clear") into system("cls")